# Changing all the values in an js object to 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

Is it possible to change all the values in an object to 0, without having to type them one by one?

Here is the object example:

```
var obj = {
 sth: {
  sth1: 15,
  sth2: 25,
  sth3: 0
 },
}
```

Set all the values of **obj.sth** to 0, without having to type:

```
obj.sth.sth1 = 0;
obj.sth.sth2 = 0;
obj.sth.sth3 = 0;
```

Having over 100 values that need to be reset back to 0 method above is kind of painful.

Also, using

```
document.getElementById(id1).innerHTML = obj.sth.sth1;
document.getElementById(id2).innerHTML = obj.sth.sth2;
document.getElementById(id3).innerHTML = obj.sth.sth3;
```

and so on to update the values after the user resets them... For this I'm thinking of making an array:

```
var ids = [
 "sth1",
 "sth2",
 "sth3"
]
```

And then:

```
for( i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
 document.getElementById(ids[i]).innerHTML = "0";
}
```

Is the method for updating HTML document good? I'd still have to type all the ids and values in an array but at least it'll be more transparent. Maybe there's a better method? I assume that, to update values in an object I'd also need a loop, but nothing comes to mind... Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `0 !== '0'` ...

Comment: maybe [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to iterate in an object:

```
for(var key in obj.sth) {
  obj.sth[key] = 0;
}
```

and to assign the value to the html maybe set an especific class to the elements and then iterate over all of them will help you more instead of using id

Comment: You mean with getElementsByClassName? Never thought of it that way before, that's actually a very good idea! I will look into it right away

Comment: I have decided to go with this answer. I can understand perfectly what it does and it works. Thanks, and thanks to everyone else for helping out as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single loop and assign to all properties `0` and set the elements as well with the value of the properties.

Use

- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for getting all own properties of an object
- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for iterating an array

```js
var obj = { sth: { sth1: 15, sth2: 25, sth3: 0 } };

Object.keys(obj.sth).forEach(function (key) {
    obj.sth[key] = 0;
    document.getElementById(key).innerHTML = obj.sth[key];
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<div id="sth1">foo</div>
<div id="sth2">foo</div>
<div id="sth3">foo</div>
```

Comment: what is `k` in `getElementById(k)` ?

Comment: a typo, should be `key`

Comment: Is this a private function? I'm new to JS and don't fully understand how to use them, but will try this method as well and see which one works best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use a for in loop

```
for (prop in obj.sth) {
 if(obj.sth.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
  obj.sth[prop] = 0;
 }
}
```